# Django or PHP? Which is my Future?

Tags: php, django

I started to learn Python. What do you prefer for my future. Should i learn Django or PHP to build sites. Is there a review about Django vs PHP?

Comment: You could take a look at [Django vs PHP+framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852876/django-vs-phpframework), or [PHP, Python & Django](http://www.nerdydork.com/php-python-django.html), or [Why PHP Is Fun and Easy But Python Is Marriage Material](http://onstartups.com/tabid/3339/bid/20493/Why-PHP-Is-Fun-and-Easy-But-Python-Is-Marriage-Material.aspx), or [PHP vs. Django](http://blog.lubico.biz/2011/09/english-php-vs-django/) or [Python & Django for PHP Refugees](http://j4mie.github.com/python-and-django-for-php-refugees/#slide1).